# Setting up DNN 6.2 to install new environment but cannot browse to pages. Error 404

Tags: iis-7.5, dotnetnuke

I am setting up a Dev site and went through all the steps (multiple times now) and it continues to give error 404.

I created the ap_Dev application pool, gave rights on the folder for the ap_dev user, created the web site, assigned it to the appPool, yet it continues to not allow me to browse to it.  I spent a full day troubleshooting this yesterday; it doesn't make sense to me.  The steps are not that hard.  Can anybody offer me some direction?

Thank you

Comment: Is Default.aspx listed in the website documents in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are going to the right address... ex if you unzipped the dnn Site in a folder called DNN then you should go to DNN.yourwebsite.com.... The way I found around this is after unzipping all filed into the dnn folder, move them all out of there and into the root of the server.... Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Make sure .NET is installed and registered properly with IIS?

aspnet_regiis.exe -i

http://forums.iis.net/t/1181330.aspx?Reinstall+IIS7